# my data is not adding in to my firebase real time database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

my data is not adding in to my firebase real time database. I have facing the problem during sending data in firebase real time database. It gives an error ***config_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_.default.database is not a function**.

I also import 'firebase/database' in my  firebase.js file.

```js
import firebase from "../../config/firebase"
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, FacebookAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";


const facebook_login=()=>{
    return (dispatch)=>{
        const provider = new FacebookAuthProvider();
        const auth = getAuth();
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log("Facebook Login")

            var user = result.user;
            var credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
            var accessToken = credential.accessToken;
            let create_user={
                name:user.displayName,
                email:user.email,
                profile:user.photoURL,
                uid:user.uid
            }

            firebase.database().ref('/').child(`users/${user.uid}`).set(create_user)
            .then(()=>{
                alert("Login Successfull")
            })
        
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            const email = error.email;
            const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
            console.log(errorMessage)
        });
    }
}

export{
    facebook_login
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the new Modular SDK, you should not use the `firebase.database()` namespaced syntax.

```
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";

const db = getDatabase();
set(ref(db, `users/${user.uid}`), create_user);
```

You can learn more about the modular syntax in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#write_data).